# How to create spouse variable?

Tags: r, merge

I have a data of couples, with variables : 'household number', 'head of household' , 'education', 'income'. 'household number' is the id number that is uniquely assigned to each household. 'head of household' is whether the person is the head of the household ( 1 = head of household, 2 = spouse of head of the household), 'education' and 'income' is education level and income of individual respectively. For example, data looks like below.

```
'household_number'  'head_of_household'  'education'  'income'
        1                     1              high       1000
        1                     2              low        100
        3                     1              medium     500
        3                     2              high       800
        4                     2              high       800
        4                     1              high       800
        9                     1              low        150
        9                     2              low        200
```

I want to create spouse's variable for each individual. So that data looks like below. Where 'spouse edu' is spouse's education level and 'spouse inc' is spouse's income.

```
'household_number'  'head_of_household'  'education'  'income' 'spouse_edu' 'spouse_inc'
        1                     1              high       1000      low         100
        1                     2              low        100       high        1000
        3                     1              medium     500       high        800
        3                     2              high       800       medium      500
        4                     2              high       800       high        800
        4                     1              high       800       high        800
        9                     1              low        150       low         200
        9                     2              low        200       low         150
```

I have very large dataset so I am looking for simple way to do this. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Below is reproducible example syntax.

```
household_number <- c(1,1,3,3,4,4,9,9)
head_of_household <- c(1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2)
education <- c("high", "low", "medium", "high", "high", "high", "low", "low")
income <- c(1000, 100, 500, 800, 800, 800, 150, 200)

data <- data.frame(household_number, head_of_household, education, income)
```

Comment: it's easy to get a spouse: just `git wife`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `base::rev` and `dplyr` here.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
 group_by(household_number) %>% 
 mutate(spouse_income = rev(income),
        spouse_education = rev(education)) %>% 
 ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 6
#  household_number head_of_household education income spouse_income spouse_education
#             <dbl>             <dbl>    <fctr>  <dbl>         <dbl>           <fctr>
#1                1                 1      high   1000           100              low
#2                1                 2       low    100          1000             high
#3                3                 1    medium    500           800             high
#4                3                 2      high    800           500           medium
#5                4                 2      high    800           800             high
#6                4                 1      high    800           800             high
#7                9                 1       low    150           200              low
#8                9                 2       low    200           150              low
```

---

A solution using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, c("spouse_income", "spouse_education") := .(rev(income), rev(education)),
            by = household_number][]

# same as
# setDT(data)[, `:=`(spouse_income = rev(income), 
#                    spouse_education = rev(education)),
#             by = household_number][]
```

---

In `base R` one could do

```
transform(data, 
          spouse_income = ave(income, household_number, FUN = rev),
          spouse_education = ave(education, household_number, FUN = rev))
```

Comment: really nice solution to `switch` the rows, which is what the OP wanted. `group_by() %>% mutate()` is clever

Answer (score 1):

The other way to solve this using `shift` in `data.table`. It will be 2 step process though.

First group by on `household_number` and fill spouse details of 1st set using `shift` with `lag`

```
    data[,':='(
      spouse_edu = shift(education),
      spouse_inc = shift(income)),
      by = household_number]
> data
   household_number head_of_household education income spouse_edu spouse_inc
1:                1                 1      high   1000         NA         NA
2:                1                 2       low    100       high       1000
3:                3                 1    medium    500         NA         NA
4:                3                 2      high    800     medium        500
5:                4                 2      high    800         NA         NA
6:                4                 1      high    800       high        800
7:                9                 1       low    150         NA         NA
8:                9                 2       low    200        low        150
```

Now, fill spouse details for other set using `lead` type of `shift`. Make sure we don't replace spouse details already filled in or updated.

```
    data[,':='(
      spouse_edu = ifelse( is.na(spouse_edu), shift(education, type="lead"), spouse_edu) ,
      spouse_inc = ifelse( is.na(spouse_inc), shift(income, type="lead"), spouse_inc)),
      by = household_number]
> data
   household_number head_of_household education income spouse_edu spouse_inc
1:                1                 1      high   1000        low        100
2:                1                 2       low    100       high       1000
3:                3                 1    medium    500       high        800
4:                3                 2      high    800     medium        500
5:                4                 2      high    800       high        800
6:                4                 1      high    800       high        800
7:                9                 1       low    150        low        200
8:                9                 2       low    200        low        150
```